# Simple Appium test in Azure Pipeline - how do I fix the failing build step (vstest)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Given:
Appium Windows Application Driver
Visual Studio 2019 solution
  WPF Project .Net 4.7.2
  Unit Test MSTest .Net 4.7.2
Azure DevOps Pipelines

I have a minimalist solution with a WPF project that just has a label "Hello World." In the unit test project I'm using Appium to test the existence of Hello World.  Very simple and runs successfully locally.

However, when I put in build in Azure DevOps my one and only test fails and I can't figure out why.

Here's the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#ui-testing-in-visible-ui-mode) that says Microsoft hosted agents are preconfigured to run Appium Tests.

Here's a [link to my Azure DevOps](https://dev.azure.com/rodsandev01/AppiumPractice/_git/RsSolution6Repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below error is abstracted from the vstest task log. It seems the WinAppDriver didnot startup correctly in the hosted agent.

`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
...
at UnitTestProject1.WpfAppSession.Setup() in d:\a\1\s\RsSolution6\UnitTestProject1\WpfAppSession.cs:line 31
   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.ClassInitialize(TestContext context) in d:\a\1\s\RsSolution6\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 20`

There's now a dedicated [WinAppDriver Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WinAppDriver.winappdriver-pipelines-task) Task available on the Azure Marketplace to help you easily enable and configure WinAppDriver from inside your DevOps Pipeline. See 
[WinAppDriver in CI with Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Docs/CI_AzureDevOps.md).

Install **WinAppDriver** task to your organization, and add it in your pipeline to start and stop winappdriver.

```
- task: Windows Application Driver@0
  inputs:
    OperationType: Start

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: Windows Application Driver@0
  inputs:
    OperationType: Stop
```